# can't found open Splice mobile on Linux?

Tags: mobile, data-distribution-service

**Good morning.
I tried to install open splice mobile (DDS for mobile) on linux and i would like to find the building version (zip version) but i didn't find it in the site i get only vortex version which are binary file. if someone have an idea how i can get the last version of open splice mobile.** 
i tried this tutorial : [www.prismtech.com/download-documents/1322](http://www.prismtech.com/download-documents/1322)
but it doesn't give me any link to the middleware. When i open the software donwload pages in the website of prismtech http://www.prismtech.com/vortex/software-downloads i didn't find opensplice mobile version.
Any help please.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be directed to the Vortex OpenSplice team directly.

Answer (score 1):

OpenSplice Mobile is now Vortex Cafe. Vortex Cafe is part of the Vortex Evaluation Bundle for Linux which can be downloaded from: http://www.prismtech.com/vortex/software-downloads